# Spring cloud gateway 2.5 with eureka return 404

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-gateway

I'm trying to build a gateway with load balancer by using spring-cloud-gateway
But when I hit gateway, it gives me 404 instead of routing me to the registered service in eureka

I don't want to use auto-discover feature, so I use manual routing instead.

my code is uploaded here :
https://github.com/gry77/poc-spring-cloud-gateway

How can I fix it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got answer from github, I must include ReWritePath to get it works

```
spring:
  application:
    name: api-gateway
  cloud:
    gateway:
      discovery:
        locator:
          lower-case-service-id: true
          enabled: false
      routes:
        - id: my-service
          uri: lb://my-service
          predicates:
            - Path=/service/**
          filters:
            - RewritePath=/service(?<segment>/?.*), /${segment}
```